# Track Roles/Identities which are deleting/updating/inserting Items in DynamoDB Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm searching for a method to track the identities which are doing modifications on my table besides the application service itself. In the beginning I though there could be two options, but:

- CloudTrail - the documentation ([Logging DynamoDB Operations by Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html)) says, as far as I understood, I'd be only able to track changes made to the infrastructure itself, but not to the actual use of a table.
- DynamoDB Streams - I'd guessed that the modifying identity is also passed in a stream event, but actually it's not. I'm using `NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES` as the stream type.

Am I overlooking something or is there probably another possibility anywhere else? The streams event does pass me an EventID. Is this of use somewhere?

Grateful for any tips on how to solve this, even if it's a complete different approach.

Comment: Are you sure about Streams? Docs show that there is [userIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_Record.html) in the stream event record.

Comment: At least for modifications, I didn't see this field. I only received `eventID`, `eventName`, `eventVersion`, `eventSource`, `awsRegion`, `dynamodb` & `eventSourceARN`

Comment: I see. Maybe its only for deletions then.

Comment: Documentation is not super clear about this. I don't know why this should be a 'delete-only' field though... information could be useful in any case. Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS CloudTrail now supports logging for DynamoDB actions!

[AWS CloudTrail Adds Logging of Data Events for Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/aws-cloudtrail-adds-logging-of-data-events-for-amazon-dynamoDB/)